# Subquery select using UNION

Tags: mysql, subquery, union, correlated-subquery

```
CREATE TABLE newsarticles
    (katernenID int, Buitenland int, Economie int, Sport int, Cultuur int, Wetenschap int, Media int, userID int);

INSERT INTO newsarticles
    (katernenID, Buitenland, Economie, Sport, Cultuur, Wetenschap, Media, userID)
VALUES
    (1, 24, 5, 52, 3, 2, 3, 1),
    (3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 51, 66, 5),
    (4, 50, 2, 67, 41, 1, 54, 6),
    (5, 30, 1, 79, 0, 0, 12, 7),
    (6, 9, 26, 0, 100, 11, 0, 8),
    (7, 2, 14, 8, 1, 33, 98, 9),
    (8, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 10);



SELECT
  userID,GROUP_CONCAT(amt ORDER BY amt DESC) AS four_highest
FROM
(
  SELECT userID, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, NAME, amt FROM (
    SELECT userID, Buitenland AS amt, 'Buitenland' AS NAME UNION
    SELECT userID, Economie, 'Economie'  UNION
    SELECT userID, Sport, 'Sport' UNION
    SELECT userID, Cultuur, 'Cultuur'  UNION
    SELECT userID, Wetenschap, 'Wetenschap'  UNION
    SELECT userID, Media, 'Media' 
         FROM( SELECT katernenID, Buitenland, Economie, Sport, Cultuur, Wetenschap, Media, userID FROM newsarticles  ) temp

  ) amounts, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) top4
GROUP BY userid
```

I want to make UNION like in above query, But Union is not Working. UNION needs FROM statement immediately.
Like:

```
    SELECT userID, Wetenschap, 'Wetenschap'  
                 FROM( SELECT katernenID, Buitenland, Economie, Sport, Cultuur, Wetenschap, Media, userID FROM newsarticles  ) temp
                 UNION
    SELECT userID, Media, 'Media' 
         FROM( SELECT katernenID, Buitenland, Economie, Sport, Cultuur, Wetenschap, Media, userID FROM newsarticles  ) temp
```

But I can't repeat FROM statement, there are too many calculations in subquery. Is there a way to do this or am I missing something?

OR

i want a new column with max(a_percentage,b_percentage,c_percentage),SecondMAX(a_percentage,b_percentage,c_percentage),ThirdMAX(a_percentage,b_percentage,c_percentage)

```
    SELECT id,a,b,c,a_percentage,b_percentage,c_percentage
    -- -------------------------max percentage
    GREATEST(axis_per, hdfc_per,icici_per,citi_per ) AS max_per,
    FROM (
      SELECT id,a,b,c,
      IFNULL(a*100/a+b+c+d,0) AS a_percentage,
      IFNULL(b*100/a+b+c+d,0) AS b_percentage,
      IFNULL(c*100/a+b+c+d,0) AS c_percentage
      FROM test
        WHERE TIME > '2012-01-01'
        GROUP BY id
      ) A
```

Comment: out of your structure and sample records, what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to use just the table name in the `FROM`, and alias the column on each row, something like:

```
SELECT
  userID,GROUP_CONCAT(amt ORDER BY amt DESC) AS four_highest
FROM
(
  SELECT userID, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, NAME, amt FROM (
    SELECT userID, Buitenland AS amt, 'Buitenland' AS NAME FROM newsarticles NAME UNION
    SELECT userID, Economie, 'Economie'  FROM newsarticles UNION
    SELECT userID, Sport, 'Sport'  FROM newsarticles UNION
    SELECT userID, Cultuur, 'Cultuur'  FROM newsarticles UNION
    SELECT userID, Wetenschap, 'Wetenschap'  FROM newsarticles UNION
    SELECT userID, Media, 'Media' FROM newsarticles
) amounts, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) top4
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: you are totally correct, but i can't fetch data from table like that. this statement is dummy "SELECT katernenID, Buitenland, Economie, Sport, Cultuur, Wetenschap, Media, userID FROM newsarticles". Instead of this there is too much calculation in inner query and some new column that comes from calculation.

Comment: Could you post an example in the question please?